# iis7.5 and classic application pool

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pools

I have windows 2008 - 64 bit and IIS7.5 , I can't use web sites under Classic Application pool. if I set Classic application pool, site shows error 404.17 , and try to use static handler for it's content.

If I use integrated application pool then some of my sites that use custom http module in their web.config dont work correctly.
How can I use classic application pool?

Thanks

UPDATE: if I set Enable 32-bit ... to true , classic application pool works

Comment: Good man! I was about to answer then saw the update. now answer your own question below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I set Enable 32-bit ... to true , classic application pool works